# How to implement CFB8 mode with Triple DES for decryption using CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, java, cryptojs, cfb-mode

I have to decrypt the data which encrypted in java server.
In java server encrypted text using triple des(mode:CFB8, padding:NoPadding)
For decrypt, I tried encrypting such as java server
Below is posted the java source code.

```
private final static String keyString = "123456789012345678901234";
private final static String ivString = "abcdefgh";


public static String encrypt(String data) throws Exception {


    KeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyString.getBytes());
    SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede").generateSecret(keySpec);
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivString.getBytes());
    Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CFB8/NoPadding");
    ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    byte[] valeur = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(valeur);

    return new String(Base64.encode(enc, Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");
}
```

And below code is my code.

```
var key="123456789012345678901234";
var iv = "abcdefgh";   
var iv1 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);   
var key1 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);   
var encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt("asdfg", key1, { 
    iv:iv1,
    mode:CryptoJS.mode.CFB,
    padding:CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
});
```

But I can't get the same result of both.

When I changed "CFB8" to "CFB" in the Java code, I get the same result.

How can implement the CFB8 in CryptoJS?

Answer (score 1):

CFB is mode of operation with a shift register. The encryption and decryption happens in segments which have the same size as the shift register and are smaller than the block size.

The problem is that CryptoJS' CFB implementation only supports segment sizes exactly the same as the block size of the used block cipher. This means that when you use AES it will be a segment size of 128-bit.

I've implemented a variable segment size version of CFB which supports all segment sizes that are a power of 2 including 1-bit up to the block size:

```js
/**
 * Cipher Feedback block mode with segment size parameter according to
 * http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf. 
 * The segment size can be anything from 1 bit up to the block size of the 
 * underlying block cipher.
 * 
 * Current limitation: only segment sizes that divide the block size evenly 
 * are supported.
 */
CryptoJS.mode.CFBb = (function () {
    var C = CryptoJS;
        CFBb = C.lib.BlockCipherMode.extend(),
        WordArray = C.lib.WordArray;

    /**
     * Shifts the array by n bits to the left. Zero bits are added as the 
     * least significant bits. This operation modifies the current array.
     * 
     * @param {WordArray} wordArray WordArray to work on
     * @param {int} n Bits to shift by
     * 
     * @returns the WordArray that was passed in
     */
    var bitshift = function(wordArray, n){
        var carry = 0,
            words = wordArray.words,
            wres,
            skipped = 0,
            carryMask;
        if (n > 0) {
            while(n > 31) {
                // delete first element:
                words.splice(0, 1);

                // add `0` word to the back
                words.push(0);

                n -= 32;
                skipped++;
            }
            if (n == 0) {
                // 1. nothing to shift if the shift amount is on a word boundary
                // 2. This has to be done, because the following algorithm computes 
                // wrong values only for n==0
                return carry;
            }
            for(var i = words.length - skipped - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                wres = words[i];
                words[i] <<= n;
                words[i] |= carry;
                carry = wres >>> (32 - n);
            }
        } else if (n < 0) {
            while(n < -31) {
                // insert `0` word to the front:
                words.splice(0, 0, 0);

                // remove last element:
                words.length--;

                n += 32;
                skipped++;
            }
            if (n == 0) {
                // nothing to shift if the shift amount is on a word boundary
                return carry;
            }
            n = -n;
            carryMask = (1 << n) - 1;
            for(var i = skipped; i < words.length; i++) {
                wres = words[i] & carryMask;
                words[i] >>>= n;
                words[i] |= carry;
                carry = wres << (32 - n);
            }
        }
        return carry;
    };

    /**
     * Negates all bits in the WordArray. This manipulates the given array.
     * 
     * @param {WordArray} wordArray WordArray to work on
     * 
     * @returns the WordArray that was passed in
     */
    var neg = function(wordArray){
        var words = wordArray.words;
        for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            words[i] = ~words[i];
        }
        return wordArray;
    };

    CFBb.Encryptor = CFBb.extend({
        processBlock: function(words, offset){
            processBlock.call(this, words, offset, true);
        }
    });

    CFBb.Decryptor = CFBb.extend({
        processBlock: function(words, offset){
            processBlock.call(this, words, offset, false);
        }
    });

    function processBlock(words, offset, encryptor) {
        // Shortcuts
        var self = this;
        var cipher = self._cipher;
        var blockSize = cipher.blockSize * 32; // in bits
        var prev = self._prevBlock;
        var segmentSize = cipher.cfg.segmentSize; // in bits
        var i, j;
        var currentPosition;

        // Create a bit mask that has a comtinuous slice of bits set that is as big as the segment
        var fullSegmentMask = [];
        for(i = 31; i < segmentSize; i += 32) {
            fullSegmentMask.push(0xffffffff);
        }
        // `s` most signiicant bits are set:
        fullSegmentMask.push(((1 << segmentSize) - 1) << (32 - segmentSize));
        for(i = fullSegmentMask.length; i < words.length; i++) {
            fullSegmentMask.push(0);
        }

        fullSegmentMask = WordArray.create(fullSegmentMask);

        // some helper variables
        var slidingSegmentMask = fullSegmentMask.clone(),
            slidingSegmentMaskShifted = slidingSegmentMask.clone(),
            slidingNegativeSegmentMask,
            prevCT;

        // shift the mask according to the current offset
        bitshift(slidingSegmentMaskShifted, -offset * 32);

        for(i = 0; i < blockSize/segmentSize; i++) {
            if (!prev) {
                prev = self._iv.slice(0); // clone

                // Remove IV for subsequent blocks
                self._iv = undefined;
            } else {
                // Prepare the iteration by concatenating the unencrypted part of the previous block and the previous ciphertext

                prev = WordArray.create(prev);
                bitshift(prev, segmentSize);
                prev = prev.words;
                previousCiphertextSegment = self._ct;

                // fill previous ciphertext up to the block size
                while(previousCiphertextSegment.length < blockSize / 32) {
                    previousCiphertextSegment.push(0);
                }
                previousCiphertextSegment = WordArray.create(previousCiphertextSegment);

                // move to the back
                bitshift(previousCiphertextSegment, -blockSize + segmentSize);

                // put together
                for (var j = 0; j < prev.length; j++) {
                    prev[j] |= previousCiphertextSegment.words[j];
                }
            }

            currentPosition = offset * 32 + i * segmentSize;

            // move segment in question to the front of the array
            var plaintextSlice = WordArray.create(words.slice(0));
            bitshift(plaintextSlice, currentPosition);

            if (!encryptor) {
                self._ct = plaintextSlice.words.slice(0, Math.ceil(segmentSize / 32));
            }

            var segKey = prev.slice(0); // clone
            cipher.encryptBlock(segKey, 0);

            // Encrypt segment
            for (j = 0; j < Math.ceil(segmentSize / 32); j++) {
                plaintextSlice.words[j] ^= segKey[j];
            }

            // Filter only the current segment
            for (j = 0; j < plaintextSlice.words.length; j++) {
                plaintextSlice.words[j] &= fullSegmentMask.words[j];
            }

            if (encryptor) {
                self._ct = plaintextSlice.words.slice(0, Math.ceil(segmentSize / 32));
            }

            // remove the segment from the plaintext array
            slidingNegativeSegmentMask = neg(slidingSegmentMaskShifted.clone());
            for (j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                words[j] &= slidingNegativeSegmentMask.words[j];
            }

            // move filtered ciphertext segment to back to the correct place
            bitshift(plaintextSlice, -currentPosition);

            // add filtered ciphertext segment to the plaintext/ciphertext array
            for (j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                words[j] |= plaintextSlice.words[j];
            }

            // shift the segment mask further along
            bitshift(slidingSegmentMask, -segmentSize);
            bitshift(slidingSegmentMaskShifted, -segmentSize);
        }
        self._prevBlock = prev;
    }

    return CFBb;
}());
```

You should use an appropriate padding. CryptoJS uses PKCS#7 padding by default. The best padding for CFB8 would be no padding at all (which you already use).

Example:

```
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
var encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt("message", key, {
    iv: iv, 
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFBb, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
    segmentSize: 8
});
var recoveredPlaintext = CryptoJS.TripleDES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFBb,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding,
    segmentSize: 8
});
console.log(recoveredPlaintext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

Since this is using a random IV, the only way to see whether the Java and JavaScript implementations are compatible, is to encrypt in one and decrypt in the other in both directions.

Keep in mind that since the IV is random, you need to send it along with the ciphertext. Since it doesn't need to be secret, you can easily prepend it to the ciphertext and slice it off before decryption.

This code is a custom copy from my repository on GitHub: [**artjomb/cryptojs-extension**](https://github.com/artjomb/cryptojs-extension).