# Different encryption values from NodeJs Crypto and CryptoJS library

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, encryption, cryptojs

I am doing Encryption and Decryption using both NodeJS Crypto and CryptoJS library in both front-end and backend. I am able to do the encryption using NodeJS Crypto which works perfectly fine and the encrypted string is also consistent with the Java encryption. But when I use, CryptoJS library the encryption string does not as expected. I provide below the standalone Typescript code.

Please help me. I am using **aes-256-cfb8** Algorithm. Is it because of this Algorithm which may not be supported by CryptoJS library? Please give me some direction, I am struck now.

```ts
import * as crypto from "crypto";
import CryptoJS, { mode } from "crypto-js";

export class Test3 {

    private static readonly CRYPTO_ALGORITHM = 'aes-256-cfb8'
    private static readonly DEFAULT_IV: string = "0123456789123456";

    // NodeJS Crypto - Works fine
    public encryptValue(valueToEncrypt: string, secretKey: string): string {
        let encryptedValue: string = '';
        const md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(secretKey).digest('hex');
        const key: string = md5;
        console.log("MD5 Value : ", md5);
        const iv = Buffer.from(Test3.DEFAULT_IV)
        console.log("iv: ", iv)
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(Test3.CRYPTO_ALGORITHM, key, iv);
        let encrypted = cipher.update(valueToEncrypt, 'utf8', 'base64');
        console.log("encrypted ::: ", encrypted);
        encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
        encryptedValue = encrypted;
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    // CryptoJS library - does not work
    public check3(valueToEncrypt: string, secretKey: string): void {
        const hash = CryptoJS.MD5(secretKey);
        const md5Key: string = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
        console.log("MD5 Value: ", md5Key); // Upto correct

        const IV11 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(Test3.DEFAULT_IV);
        const key11 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(md5Key);
        const data = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(valueToEncrypt);

        const enc1 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, key11, { 
            format: CryptoJS.format.OpenSSL,
            iv: IV11,
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
            
          });
          console.log("Cipher text11: ", enc1.toString());
        
    }
}

const text2Encrypt = "A brown lazy dog";
const someSecretKey: string = "projectId" + "~" + "India";
const test = new Test3();

// Using NodeJS Crypto
const enc = test.encryptValue(text2Encrypt, someSecretKey);
console.log("Encrypted Value Using NodeJS Crypto: ", enc); // ===> nJG4Fk27JZ7E5klLqFAt

// Using CryptoJS 
console.log("****************** Using CryptoJS ******************")
test.check3(text2Encrypt, someSecretKey);
```

Please help me for the method **check3()** of the above class. Also I have checked many links in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You suspect right. Both codes use different variants of the CFB mode. For CFB a segment size must be defined. The segment size of the CFB mode corresponds to the bits encrypted per encryption step, see [CFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_(CFB)).

The *crypto* module of NodeJS supports several segment sizes, e.g. 8 bits (`aes-256-cfb8`) or 128 bits (`aes-256-cfb`), while *CryptoJS* only supports a segment size of 128 bits (`CryptoJS.mode.CFB`).

If the segment size is changed to 128 bits (`aes-256-cfb`) in the *crypto* module, both ciphertexts match.

Edit:
In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31582096/9014097) you will find an extension of *CryptoJS* for the CFB mode, so that also a variable segment size, e.g. 8 bits, is supported.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco, both encrypted string when I change to `aes-256-cfb` this algorithm. But in my case it should be `aes-256-cfb8`, because it has been implemented by me in Java also which can not be used as it has been used by many modules.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Topaco. I made some changes as per Typescript structure to make it work. It is working fine. Accepted your inputs and direction.